# Recursive query - Can't get order correct based on display order column

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

I have a bill of material table (MBOM) and I am trying to write a recursive query. The parts are to be displayed under their respective parent in order defined by displayorder. I can't figure out how to get this in the correct order. The query I am using is

```
WITH tree ( id, parentid, level, displayorder, uom, quantity ) AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        parentid,
        0 as level,
        displayorder,
        uom,
        quantity
    FROM
        MBOM
    WHERE
        parentid = 47

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        c2.id,
        c2.parentid,
        tree.level + 1,
        c2.displayorder,
        c2.uom,
        c2.quantity
    FROM
        MBOM c2
        INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tree;
```

This is my raw data.

| parentid | level | id | quantity | uom | displayorder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 47 | 0 | 17 | 7.6011 | 884 | 10 |
| 47 | 0 | 6 | 8.3334 | 884 | 20 |
| 47 | 0 | 19 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 47 | 0 | 55 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 47 | 0 | 102 | 1 | 665 | 50 |
| 47 | 0 | 103 | 1 | 665 | 60 |
| 47 | 0 | 104 | 1 | 665 | 70 |
| 47 | 0 | 58 | 1 | 665 | 80 |
| 55 | 1 | 41 | 60 | 665 | 10 |
| 55 | 1 | 4 | 6 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 1 | 45 | 4 | 665 | 40 |
| 55 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 665 | 50 |
| 55 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 665 | 60 |
| 55 | 1 | 115 | 1 | 665 | 70 |
| 55 | 1 | 118 | 1 | 665 | 80 |
| 55 | 1 | 142 | 1 | 665 | 90 |
| 55 | 1 | 119 | 1 | 665 | 100 |
| 55 | 1 | 125 | 1 | 665 | 110 |
| 55 | 1 | 359 | 1 | 665 | 130 |
| 55 | 1 | 164 | 2 | 665 | 140 |
| 55 | 1 | 155 | 1 | 665 | 150 |
| 55 | 1 | 160 | 1 | 665 | 160 |
| 55 | 1 | 67 | 1 | 665 | 170 |
| 55 | 1 | 57 | 1 | 665 | 180 |
| 55 | 1 | 123 | 1 | 665 | 190 |
| 55 | 1 | 106 | 1 | 665 | 120 |
| 106 | 2 | 6 | 0.9082 | 884 | 10 |
| 106 | 2 | 92 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 106 | 2 | 131 | 3 | 665 | 40 |
| 106 | 2 | 372 | 6 | 665 | 20 |
| 131 | 3 | 130 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 131 | 3 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 67 | 2 | 66 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 67 | 2 | 5 | 6 | 665 | 20 |
| 160 | 2 | 114 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 160 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 665 | 20 |
| 164 | 2 | 163 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 164 | 2 | 12 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 359 | 2 | 6 | 0.1426 | 884 | 10 |
| 359 | 2 | 41 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 359 | 2 | 71 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 359 | 2 | 141 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 141 | 3 | 140 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 141 | 3 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 71 | 3 | 70 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 71 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 665 | 20 |
| 125 | 2 | 6 | 0.0001 | 884 | 10 |
| 125 | 2 | 93 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 125 | 2 | 161 | 2 | 665 | 40 |
| 125 | 2 | 374 | 4 | 665 | 20 |
| 161 | 3 | 162 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 161 | 3 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 119 | 2 | 6 | 0.0001 | 884 | 10 |
| 119 | 2 | 65 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 119 | 2 | 129 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 119 | 2 | 121 | 1 | 665 | 50 |
| 119 | 2 | 374 | 4 | 665 | 20 |
| 121 | 3 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 121 | 3 | 120 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 129 | 3 | 128 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 129 | 3 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 142 | 2 | 42 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 142 | 2 | 144 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 142 | 2 | 146 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 142 | 2 | 148 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 142 | 2 | 150 | 1 | 665 | 50 |
| 150 | 3 | 405 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 150 | 3 | 149 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 148 | 3 | 405 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 148 | 3 | 147 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 146 | 3 | 405 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 146 | 3 | 145 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 144 | 3 | 405 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 144 | 3 | 143 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 118 | 2 | 6 | 0.0265 | 884 | 10 |
| 118 | 2 | 41 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 118 | 2 | 117 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 118 | 2 | 81 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 115 | 2 | 6 | 0.0639 | 884 | 10 |
| 115 | 2 | 41 | 3 | 665 | 20 |
| 115 | 2 | 116 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 115 | 2 | 111 | 1 | 665 | 40 |

This is my desired result

| parentid | level | id | quantity | uom | displayorder |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0 | 47 | 1 | 665 | 0 |
| 47 | 1 | 17 | 7.6011 | 884 | 10 |
| 47 | 1 | 6 | 8.3334 | 884 | 20 |
| 47 | 1 | 19 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 47 | 1 | 55 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 55 | 2 | 41 | 60 | 665 | 10 |
| 55 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 45 | 4 | 665 | 40 |
| 55 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 665 | 50 |
| 55 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 665 | 60 |
| 55 | 2 | 115 | 1 | 665 | 70 |
| 115 | 3 | 6 | 0.0639 | 884 | 10 |
| 115 | 3 | 41 | 3 | 665 | 20 |
| 115 | 3 | 116 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 115 | 3 | 111 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 55 | 2 | 118 | 1 | 665 | 80 |
| 118 | 3 | 6 | 0.0265 | 884 | 10 |
| 118 | 3 | 41 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 118 | 3 | 117 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 118 | 3 | 81 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 55 | 2 | 142 | 1 | 665 | 90 |
| 142 | 3 | 42 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 142 | 3 | 144 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 144 | 4 | 143 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 144 | 4 | 405 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 142 | 3 | 146 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 146 | 4 | 145 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 146 | 4 | 405 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 142 | 3 | 148 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 148 | 4 | 147 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 148 | 4 | 405 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 142 | 3 | 150 | 1 | 665 | 50 |
| 150 | 4 | 149 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 150 | 4 | 405 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 119 | 1 | 665 | 100 |
| 119 | 3 | 6 | 0.0001 | 884 | 10 |
| 119 | 3 | 374 | 4 | 665 | 20 |
| 119 | 3 | 65 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 119 | 3 | 129 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 129 | 4 | 128 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 129 | 4 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 119 | 3 | 121 | 1 | 665 | 50 |
| 121 | 4 | 120 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 121 | 4 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 125 | 1 | 665 | 110 |
| 125 | 3 | 6 | 0.0001 | 884 | 10 |
| 125 | 3 | 374 | 4 | 665 | 20 |
| 125 | 3 | 93 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 125 | 3 | 161 | 2 | 665 | 40 |
| 161 | 4 | 162 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 161 | 4 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 106 | 1 | 665 | 120 |
| 106 | 3 | 6 | 0.9082 | 884 | 10 |
| 106 | 3 | 372 | 6 | 665 | 20 |
| 106 | 3 | 92 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 106 | 3 | 131 | 3 | 665 | 40 |
| 131 | 4 | 130 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 131 | 4 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 359 | 1 | 665 | 130 |
| 359 | 3 | 6 | 0.1426 | 884 | 10 |
| 359 | 3 | 41 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 359 | 3 | 71 | 1 | 665 | 30 |
| 71 | 4 | 70 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 71 | 4 | 5 | 5 | 665 | 20 |
| 359 | 3 | 141 | 1 | 665 | 40 |
| 141 | 4 | 140 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 141 | 4 | 12 | 2 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 164 | 2 | 665 | 140 |
| 164 | 3 | 163 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 164 | 3 | 12 | 1 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 155 | 1 | 665 | 150 |
| 55 | 2 | 160 | 1 | 665 | 160 |
| 160 | 3 | 114 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 160 | 3 | 5 | 3 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 67 | 1 | 665 | 170 |
| 67 | 3 | 66 | 1 | 665 | 10 |
| 67 | 3 | 5 | 6 | 665 | 20 |
| 55 | 2 | 57 | 1 | 665 | 180 |
| 55 | 2 | 123 | 1 | 665 | 190 |
| 47 | 1 | 102 | 1 | 665 | 50 |
| 47 | 1 | 103 | 1 | 665 | 60 |
| 47 | 1 | 104 | 1 | 665 | 70 |
| 47 | 1 | 58 | 1 | 665 | 80 |

Comment: While I appreciate you posting the actual and expected data, you've posted **waaaaay too much** data for anyone to sift through - please reduce your actual+expected data to something minimal, say, a handful of rows (5-10?) that demonstrate the issue in isolation.

Comment: Uhm, you don't have an `ORDER BY displayorder` anywhere in your query... and I can't see how your "expected" data is sorted...  I'm not seeing any logical pattern or arrangement.

Comment: modify your code as `SELECT * FROM tree order by parentid,displayorder;` . your desire order is based on the `parentid`,`displayorder`

Answer (score 0):

SQL will not guarantee any order without an `ORDER BY`, so you might want to add one:

```
WITH tree ( id, parentid, level, displayorder, uom, quantity ) AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        parentid,
        0 as level,
        displayorder,
        uom,
        quantity
    FROM
        MBOM
    WHERE
        parentid = 47

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        c2.id,
        c2.parentid,
        tree.level + 1,
        c2.displayorder,
        c2.uom,
        c2.quantity
    FROM
        MBOM c2
        INNER JOIN tree ON tree.id = c2.parentid
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tree
ORDER BY level, displayorder
```